# Value of this.id for same element is different between browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Raphael.js to handle an SVG map. It does great in all desktop browsers. I have a click function to fire off a few things when a given area on the map is clicked. It relies on grabbing the (this.id) of the clicked object and spitting back some results.

Problem is that it works on desktop browsers Safari, Opera, IE9, and Chrome. I tried opening same thing on a mobile android (4.0.3) browser and the value for (this.id) is not the same so the region I clicked on is not the one I get results for. The this.id of the object on the desktop is NOT equal to the this.id of the same object on the mobile browser.

I've verified the values by using alerts. What gives? How can I work around this or find the id of the clicked item in a more foolproof way?

Here's the snipped of code that matters:

```
drawnl[i].click(function(){//click function

if(dcount == mcount){
    idx = (highestid-1-this.id); // this takes the total number of markets generated up to this point, subtracts the # of markets for this current map

}else if(gens > 2){

    idx = (mcount-1)-((dcount + (gens-2))-(this.id)); // this takes the total number of markets generated up to this point, subtracts the # of markets for this current 

}else{
    idx = mcount-1-(dcount-this.id);
}   

}
```

I've confirmed that all other values are consistent except for when I grab this.id. I'm using the built-in handler from Raphael.js (http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.click)

Answer (score 0):

The id should be on the event.  In your event handler do

`var id = evt.target.id;`

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a jsfiddle so we can see what you are doing?

Shot in the dark: you could use the event object, usually the first argument passed to an event listener callback function. You can then do eventObject.currentTarget.id, which should be a reference to the node on whom the click event was triggered.

Comment: oh, like hvgotcodes says. But depending, you may need currentTarget: http://omegaluz.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/e-target-vs-e-currenttarget/